# Android SQLite: nullColumnHack parameter in insert/replace methods

Tags: android, sqlite

The Android SDK has some convenience methods for manipulating data with SQLite.  However both the [insert](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) and [replace](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#replace%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) methods use some `nullColumnHack` parameter which usage I don't understand.

The documentation explains it with the following, but what if a table has multiple columns that allow `NULL`? I really don't get it :/

> SQL doesn't allow inserting a completely empty row, so if initialValues is empty, this column [*/row for replace*] will explicitly be assigned a `NULL` value.

Answer (score 199, accepted):

Let's suppose you have a table named `foo` where all columns either allow `NULL` values or have defaults.

In some SQL implementations, this would be valid SQL:

```
INSERT INTO foo;
```

That's not valid in SQLite. You have to have at least one column specified:

```
INSERT INTO foo (somecol) VALUES (NULL);
```

Hence, in the case where you pass an empty `ContentValues` to `insert()`, Android and SQLite need some column that is safe to assign `NULL` to. If you have several such columns to choose from, pick one via the selection mechanism of your choice: roll of the dice, Magic 8-Ball(TM), coin flip, cubicle mate flip, etc.

Personally, I'd've just made it illegal to pass an empty `ContentValues` to `insert()`, but they didn't ask me... :-)