# Insert method of SQLiteDatabase

Tags: android, sqlite

The second parameter of insert method of SQLiteDatabase is `"nullColumnHack"`. WHat does this refers. What value should be passed to this parameter.

Thanks

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html explains it all

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662927/android-sqlite-nullcolumnhack-parameter-in-insert-replace-methods

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android SQLite: nullColumnHack parameter in insert/replace methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662927/android-sqlite-nullcolumnhack-parameter-in-insert-replace-methods)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Brief explanation..

nullColumnHack

optional; may be null. SQL doesn't allow inserting a completely empty row without naming at least one column name. If your provided values is empty, no column names are known and an empty row can't be inserted. If not set to null, the nullColumnHack parameter provides the name of nullable column name to explicitly insert a NULL into in the case where your values is empty.

Comment: this is same what's given in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

nullColumnHack are known and an empty row can't be inserted. If not set to null, the nullColumnHack parameter provides the name of nullable column name to explicitly insert a NULL into in the case where your values is empty.