# Duplicate data issue android sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, duplicate-data

I am creating an app in which people give scores to other persons. For that, I want to insert names of some person (say 5) to a database during installation of the app. Now the when I run the app first time everything goes fine. But when I run it second time, the data are inserted again making it 10, i.e. duplicate data. The problem is whenever I run this activity, it adds the data. What is the solution to this problem?
Here's my code:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
     public class GamePlay extends ActionBarActivity {
     //Some code-----------

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gameplay);
    //Some code----

    db=openOrCreateDatabase("MyGameData", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    try{
        db.execSQL("create table teachers(_id integer primary key autoincrement , name varchar(30) , gender varchar(2) , score integer)");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Table created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Exception 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i("Create table", e.getMessage());
    }

    // Insert values in table-------


    String str_name[]={"arun", "dhanraj", "decoder", "sanjana"};
    String str_gender[]={"m", "m", "m", "f"};

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    for(int i=0; i<str_name.length; i++){

        cv.put("name", str_name[i]);
        cv.put("gender", str_gender[i]);
        db.insert("teachers", null, cv);

    }

   //Some code------
```

Comment: For sure. You shoud **UPDATE** the existing data, if already present. You only **INSERT** new records, duplicating the information in your db.

Comment: @DerGolem : I want to insert new data during installation. No data is present at first. That's why I use INSERT. Updating is another process. So how should I insert the names and gender?

Comment: I'd do another query to see if user exists, then do what Der Golem says, and update the data.

Comment: You **could** also do **without** another query, and always use  the **REPLACE INTO** command (although slower, because it always does a check if data is  existing and decides whether to perform an INSERTion or an UPDATE). But that is the concept. You could also try to do an UPDATE and manage the returned error, this time performing an UPDATE.

Comment: @KristyWelsh : Yeah this is a solution. But running query would be a long process for say if I have 100 names and genders to insert. It would take unnecessary time. What I want is to insert the data only once and it should not be inserted when I run it the next time. The update work is separate. I have no problem with that. Is there any other method that can be used?

Comment: @DerGolem : I think you are not getting what I am trying to do. Let me be clear. I am creating the app for people to give scores to some specific names. So I want to insert the names during installation only ONCE. Now after the names are given I want when the app is run second time, it should NOT enter the names again. The scores will be updated. I have done that part. Yes, checking OR REPLACE INTO is a solution, but it will make the app slow if the no. of names are increased say 100. So what's the solution?

Comment: I understood perfectly. The slution, as indicated by others, is to include your INSERTs in the onCreate event of your DBHelper class. Then only perform UPDATEs.

Comment: @DerGolem : ya understood now. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a `SQLiteOpenHelper` class which contains some methods for database management and lifecycle like

```
onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) // Called when the database is created for the first time.
onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) //Called when the database needs to be downgraded.
onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) // Called when the database needs to be upgraded.
```

And other ones, you can have a look here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html

Following this tutorial should keep you on the good path about using this helper:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

My advice is to create some Querys like the ones that will populate and execute them after the creation of the Tables which should be there too. This way, your app will only make those inserts the first time, and keep them even if you update your database (if you don't state something else on the onUpgrade() method).

This should fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

If I get your problem right, you could use a helper class and extend SQLiteOpenHelper.

In the onCreate method you can insert the needed data. This method is called only once.

Hope this helps.